# Fullpage JS, execução em páginas diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullpage.js

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em AngularJS e estou utilizando o Fullpage.js para rolagem das páginas. Até ai tudo bem, o problema é o seguinte:

Como tenho páginas internas, preciso também utilizar a rolagem do script nestas páginas.
Porém mesmo criando a função como Scope para que funcione em todas as páginas ou criando ela com o nome diferente e iniciando em cada uma o Fullpage retorna o seguinte erro:

**fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!**

Alguém sabe como posso fazer para que quando eu iniciar a função da outra página, eu cancele a função do Fullpage da página anterior e inicie novamente a outra função do controller atual?

Segue a função que estou utilizando:

```
vm.rolagem_home = function(){

     $('#site').fullpage({
                //Navigation
                menu: '#menu',
                lockAnchors: false,
                //anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'trespage'],
                navigation: false,
                navigationPosition: 'right',
                //navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
                showActiveTooltip: false,
                slidesNavigation: true,
                slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

                //Scrolling
                css3: true,
                scrollingSpeed: 700,
                autoScrolling: true,
                fitToSection: true,
                fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
                scrollBar: false,
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                easingcss3: 'ease',
                loopBottom: false,
                loopTop: false,
                loopHorizontal: true,
                continuousVertical: false,
                //normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
                scrollOverflow: false,
                scrollOverflowOptions: null,
                touchSensitivity: 15,
                normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,

                //Accessibility
                keyboardScrolling: true,
                animateAnchor: true,
                recordHistory: true,

                //Design
                controlArrows: true,
                verticalCentered: true,
              //  sectionsColor : ['#ccc', '#fff'],
              paddingTop: '0em',
              paddingBottom: '0px',
              fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
              responsiveWidth: 0,
              responsiveHeight: 0,

                //Custom selectors
                sectionSelector: '.section',
                slideSelector: '.slide',

                //events
                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){},
                afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
                afterRender: function(){
                    $(window).load(function() {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    });
                },
                afterResize: function(){},
                afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
                    console.log(slideIndex);
                    if(slideIndex > 0){
                        $('.fp-prev').show();
                    }else{
                        $('.fp-prev').hide();
                    }
                    if(slideIndex == 6){
                        $('.fp-next').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('.fp-next').show();
                    }
                },
                onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex){

                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara, você está apenas passando via scope para outra página ou esta inicializando em outro controller?
Pelo que vi, ele permite apenas 1 load por página. Porém não sei se é um load por controller.

Agora o problema vai ocorrer se o seu outro controller for um controller filho do primeiro que você já inicializou o fullpage.js

Existe algumas diretivas que você pode se basear:

- https://github.com/hellsan631/angular-fullpage.js
- https://github.com/mmautomatizacion/angular-fullpage.js

Abraços

Comment: Tentei passar como Scope, porém não obtive sucesso, estou inicializando a função com nome diferente em cada controller, pois em cada página os id de cada section muda. Estou pensando em antes de executar novamente, dar algum destroy, algo parecido com isso: $.fullpage.destroy();

Comment: Sim, é uma alternativa. Você pode usar o `destroy('all')`.

**destroy(type)
type: can be empty or all. If all is passed, the HTML markup and styles used by fullpage.js will be removed. This way the original HTML markup, the one used before any plugin modification is made, will be maintained.**

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
if($('#agencia').fullpage() != ''){ 
        $('#agencia').fullpage.destroy('all');   
    }
```

Assim o JS detecta se já existe em execução e destroy.